# What are the mechanics to email a styled (XSLT) XML as the message body?

Tags: xml, xslt, href, email-attachments, email-client

Using Perl I'm trying to use sendmail to send a page of styled XML. If I call it up in a browser as file://mydir/myfile.xml it looks great.

On disk I have myfile.xml and myfile.xslt files. I can attach each of these and the show up as attachments. But if I try to shove the XML into the email body, will the email be clever enough to know to look at attachments when it encounters:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="myfile.xslt"?>
```

in the XML? This part is foreign to me since the href is always a disk dir in my experience.

I googled it and most sites talked about "first converting the XML to HTML" and shoving that into the body- which sounded like an extra step to me that I hope I don't need to perform.

Advice is welcomed and appreciated. I'm building some quick and dirty Perl test cases now but I thought you experts might have some insights.

Comment: Depends on the mail client. Some are smarter about it than others. But at minimum, a MIME type is a good thing to include.

Comment: thank you Sobrique, I'm conducting some trials now. If I DO need to get the HTML, then how do I derive HTML = XML + XSLT ? Normally the browser does that?

Comment: Why is the question tagged as XSLT 2.0? Browsers don't support that at all. As for referencing parts of messages, see cid: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2392.txt.

Comment: As for doing an XSLT 1.0 transformation in Perl, see http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXSLT-1.94/LibXSLT.pm.

Comment: I tried every MIME type that looked appropriate, and none changed the XML represention on the message. So I decided to try and use XML::XSLT and now I get this error: Can't locate XML/DOM/XPath .. Oddly there is an XML::XPath module, and there is also an XML/DOM directory. So either a file is missing, or expected in the wrong dir?

Comment: Martin I'm using <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" and mozilla handles it just ducky? Not sure I know what you mean...

Comment: Well, an XSLT 1.0 processor is supposed to try to run stylesheets which have a `version` greater than supported, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#forwards, but it does not mean there is any support for features like `for-each-group` or `matches` introduced in XSLT and/or XPath 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

> will the email be clever enough to know to look at attachments

No. The absolute path on your disk will not equal the absolute path on the client. Email clients have the following in common:

> popular webmail tools like Hotmail, Yahoo Mail, and Gmail all rewrite, change, and alter your code to fit it within their web-based email application.

and in the context of external stylesheets:

> some break any links to external stylesheets

Use a self-contained stylesheet:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="#style1"?>
<!DOCTYPE catalog [
  <!ATTLIST xsl:stylesheet id ID #REQUIRED>
]>
<ns>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" id="style1" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  >
    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="n"> 
      <xsl:value-of select="."/><sup>2</sup>=<xsl:value-of select=".*."/><br/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xsl:stylesheet"><!-- ignore --></xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>

  <n>2</n><n>3</n>
</ns>
```

**References**

- [8 HTML Email Tips I Wish I’d Known Sooner](http://flyingdogcreative.com/8-html-email-tips-i-wish-i-knew-sooner/)
- [Dynamic Content in Email](https://litmus.com/blog/how-to-code-a-live-dynamic-twitter-feed-in-html-email)
- [An RDF XML mapping of RFC 822/MIME](http://www.openhealth.org/xmtp/)
- [xml-stylesheet+DataPower](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/HermannSW/entry/march_20_2012_12_17_pm1?lang=en)
- [Referencing MSXML within VBA Projects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763701)